# unrar: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos6

I want to install `rar` tool, but an error occurs when I run `unrar xxx.rar`. I have install `glibc` and my computer linux kernel is `Linux MyName 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. My machine is CentOS 6.4 . What should I do ? Could someone give me some advice ? Thank you very much .
This is installed `libstdc++` detail :

```
>yum list | grep libstdc++
compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64            3.2.3-69.el6              @base           
libstdc++.x86_64                      4.4.7-4.el6               @base           
libstdc++-devel.x86_64                4.4.7-4.el6               @base           
compat-libstdc++-296.i686             2.96-144.el6              base            
compat-libstdc++-33.i686              3.2.3-69.el6              base            
libstdc++.i686                        4.4.7-4.el6               base            
libstdc++-devel.i686                  4.4.7-4.el6               base            
libstdc++-docs.x86_64                 4.4.7-4.el6               base
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: just install the libstdc++ package

Comment: @gino pilotinoThanks for your answer . I have installed `libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64`. Does is't libstdc++ version problem ??

Comment: if unrar is in your PATH try `ldd <backtick>which unrar<backtick>` to get the list of missing packages

Comment: did you installed unrar with yum also?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your unrar version to x64. So, you can find the download version in: [Rarlab website](http://rarlab.com/download.htm) (as sudo):

```
tar -xvzf rarlinux-x64-5.5.b4.tar.gz
```

--Move the rar folder to /usr/local:

```
mv rar /usr/local/
```

--Go to /usr/local/bin:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

--Create a link for unrar:

```
ln -s /usr/local/rar/unrar
```

--in command, type:

```
unrar x filename.rar
```

Best Regards,
José Junior